# Mark repeated id with a-b relationship in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a relationship between repeated ID's in dataframe. For example take 91, so 91 is repeated 4 times so for first 91 entry **first** column row value will be updated to **A** and **second** will be updated to **B** then for next row of 91, first will be updated to **B** and second will updated to **C**  then for next first will be **C** and second will be **D** and so on and this same relationship will be there for all duplicated ID's.
For ID's that are not repeated first will marked as **A**.

| id | first | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 0 | 0 |
| 09 | 0 | 0 |
| 91 | 0 | 0 |
| 91 | 0 | 0 |
| 91 | 0 | 0 |
| 91 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 | 0 |
| 15 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | 0 | 0 |
| 01 | 0 | 0 |
| 01 | 0 | 0 |
| 01 | 0 | 0 |

**Expected output:**

| id | first | other |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | A | 0 |
| 09 | A | 0 |
| 91 | A | B |
| 91 | B | C |
| 91 | C | D |
| 91 | D | E |
| 15 | A | B |
| 15 | B | C |
| 12 | A | 0 |
| 01 | A | B |
| 01 | B | C |
| 01 | C | D |

I using `df.iterrows()` for this but that's becoming very messy code and will be slow if dataset increases is there any easy way of doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a mapping using a `cumcount` per group as source:

```
from string import ascii_uppercase

# mapping dictionary
# this is an example, you can use any mapping
d = dict(enumerate(ascii_uppercase))
# {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C'...}

g = df.groupby('id')
c = g.cumcount()
m = g['id'].transform('size').gt(1)

df['first'] = c.map(d)
df.loc[m, 'other'] = c[m].add(1).map(d)
```

Output:

```
    id first other
0   11     A     0
1    9     A     0
2   91     A     B
3   91     B     C
4   91     C     D
5   91     D     E
6   15     A     B
7   15     B     C
8   12     A     0
9    1     A     B
10   1     B     C
11   1     C     D
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
    id
0   12
1    9
2   91
3   91
4   91
5   91
6   15
7   15
8   12
9    1
10   1
11   1
```

Doing:

```
# Count ids per group
df['first'] = df.groupby('id').cumcount()
# convert to letters and make other col
m = df.groupby('id').filter(lambda x: len(x)>1).index
df.loc[m, 'other'] = df['first'].add(66).apply(chr)
df['first'] = df['first'].add(65).apply(chr)
# fill in missing with 0
df['other'] = df['other'].fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
    id first other
0   11     A     0
1    9     A     0
2   91     A     B
3   91     B     C
4   91     C     D
5   91     D     E
6   15     A     B
7   15     B     C
8   12     A     0
9    1     A     B
10   1     B     C
11   1     C     D
```

Comment: My `m` and mozway's `m` do the same thing, but their version is better~ Besides that our answers are actually very similar.